# Reescribir URL con .htaccess para múltiples parámetros opcionales

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

tengo lo siguiente código:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1&sp=$2 [L]
```

Lo que hace es

> localhost/proyecto/val1/val2

pero al no poner un segundo parámetro me da un error 404, es decir

> localhost/proyecto/val1/

Me podrían ayudar soy nuevo en esto y no se nada de esto, este es un código que me encontré en aquí mismo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786340/rewrite-url-with-htaccess-for-multiple-parameters

Comment: Probablemente tu error sea la `/` al final de la URL... Probá con la barra al final como opcional: `^([^/]+)/?$` para la primera regla; y `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` para la segunda

Answer (score 1):

saludos. Haz probado hacerlo de esta forma

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1&sp=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?p=$1&sp=$2 [L]
```

Lo coloco asi por seguir tu patron, pero no es muy recomendable empezar la raiz de una pagina con un parametro, lo ideal, seria predefinir un prefijo, tal como

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^raiz/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^raiz/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^raiz/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1&sp=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^raiz/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?p=$1&sp=$2 [L]
```

Creeme, te evitara muchos dolores de cabeza mas adelante

Comment: Hola muchas gracias pero me lo podrías explicar a groso modo ya que no entiendo mucho de lo que veo y eso me podría ayudar mucho. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por cierto me da este error: [Sat Feb 25 00:05:27.557704 2017] [core:alert] [pid 3663] [client ::1:58676] /var/www/html/proyecto/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters pero no se porque?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con algo así:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
Rewriterule ^(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?p=$1&sp=$2
```

Si necesitas más info sobre .htaccess puedes ver más [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174146/eliminar-extensiones-php-html-con-htaccess/174147#174147).