# Eliminar extensiones php/html con .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Quiero eliminar extensiones php/html con .htaccess tengo este código:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

pero no me modifica la url es decir la url actual es esta ejemplo:

> dominio/carpeta/home.php

quiero que quede

> dominio/carpeta/home

Comment: Hola @Johendry, deseas acceder a una dirección específica por ejemplo:
http://localhost/systemsphp/quito/public/personas
sin poner el .php al final? eso es lo que deseas hacer verdad?

Comment: seria asi localhost/aplicacion-1/mayorista/example.php lo guardo en la raiz que es aplicacion-1 y la carpeta que tiene todas las funciones es mayorista

Comment: tengo otra duda como podria hacer si el usuario coloca arriba por ejemplo este es el archivo php example.php que con lo trabajado se ve asi example que lo veo exelente pero como hago para que el usuario asi colocoque al final en la url el .php le carge example sin su extencion gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eso que intentas hacer se llama establecer URLs amigables y, si buscas un poco, hay muchísimos tutoriales en google, no obstante, voy a intentar explicártelo un poco:

En primer lugar, un ejemplo de URL amigable sería algo asi:

> www.laredsocialquesea.com/profile/pepe

Una URL no amigable sería, siguiendo el mismo ejemplo, algo así:

> www.laredsocialquesea.com/SearchProfile.php?nick=pepe

Sabiendo esto, en el archivo .htaccess para crear URLs amigables podríamos hacer algo así:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
Rewriterule ^profile/(.+)$ archivo.php?nick=$1
```

Vamos a explicar un poco el código: En primer lugar tenemos la línea `RewriteEngine on`, lo cual activa las modificaciones en las urls. En la segunda y tercera línea tenemos las `RewriteCond`, la primera evita las reglas que coincidan con directorios y la segunda evita que coincidan con archivos.

Y por último tenemos la línea de `RewriteRule`, con esta vamos a ir por partes:

En primer lugar tenemos el símbolo `^`, que significa que comienza la expresión.

Después tenemos `profile/(.+)`, lo que significa que tras la url tiene que haber un valor, es decir `(.+)`:

> www.laredsocialquesea.com/profile/valor

Este valor se determina tras el $, y se puede ver que es el nombre del archivo, con su extensión y todo, pero con un añadido, que viene a ser `$1`.

`$1` va a ser el nombre del valor al que queramos acceder, y pueden haber más valores que puedas añadir, que sigan de la siguiente forma: `$2`, `$3`... etc. Cada valor que añadas equivale a un `(.+)` en la expresión anterior.

Por tanto, como último ejemplo, pongamos que queremos acceder a una foto del perfil de nuestro personaje ficticio pepe directamente. La Url amigable sería algo así:

> www.laredsocialquesea.com/profile/pepe/photos/5

Y la Url no amigable sería asi:

> www.laredsocialquesea.com/SearchProfile.php?nick=pepe&photoid=5

Por lo tanto, la regla que se debería escribir en el htaccess sería tal que así:

```
Rewriterule ^carpeta/(.+)$ $1.php
```

De esta forma podríamos usar la URL amigable para acceder.

Comment: probe tu codigo no me funciona igual guarde el htaccess en la raiz del sitio y no funciona coloque la regla como tu lo pusiste y este hace lo mismo

Comment: En tu código tienes el `(.+)` como `(.*)`, cámbialo y debería funcionar @JohendryParra

Comment: lo acabo de hacer y nada dejame probar con un nuevo proyecto solo para probar que todo este bien y te notifico

Comment: no no funciona ya probe y es como si no entrara en la carpeta de las aplicaciones que es esta

localhost/pruebahtaccess/carpeta/index

entra es en la principal en la index.php que esta en la carpeta pruebahtaccess

Comment: ya lo hice funcionar quitandole la carpeta quedaria asi Rewriterule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Comment: tengo otra duda como podria hacer si el usuario coloca arriba por ejemplo este es el archivo php example.php que con lo trabajado se ve asi example que lo veo exelente pero como hago para que el usuario asi colocoque al final en la url el .php le carge example sin su extencion gracias

Comment: @JohendryParra, en lugar de preguntar en los comentarios puedes formular otra pregunta con tus dudas, puedes poner esta pregunta de referencia como indica [Referir preguntas propias asociadas a otra pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3494/referir-preguntas-propias-asociadas-a-otra-pregunta) y si esta respuesta te ha sido de utilidad no olvides marcarla como respuesta aceptada.

Comment: @JohendryParra si sigues las instrucciones de la respuesta podrás hacerlo sin problema :)