# ¿Cómo crear un ID único de un post similar a StackOverflow?

Tags: php, mysqli, .htaccess

La URL, que emplea SO, es muy práctica, por ejemplo si se publica una pregunta con un título igual a otra pregunta existente, pueda que la ruta del título al pasar a la URL sea la misma, pero StackOverflow agrega un ID a cada publicación que hace la diferencia de las preguntas.

Ej:

```
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179431/consulta-basica-de-pdo
```

Observando la URL, se observa el siguiente ID `179431` generado en la pregunta.

Basándose al ejemplo de la URL, como puedo emplear el mismo diseño, el mismo sistema en mi aplicación de noticias, para así obtener la siguiente ruta amigable:

```
example.com/noticias/171210/mundial-rusia-2018/
```

El diseño de mi tabla está estructurada de la siguiente manera:

```
id_mini_cover    cover_page    title    description    url    ...
1                17382.jpg     ...      ...            ...    ...
```

***Preguntas***

- ¿Qué columna y de qué tipo debo agregar en mi tabla para los ID únicos de las noticias?
- ¿Cómo generar el ID único automáticamente por cada publicación de una noticia?
- ¿Qué cambios debo emplear, en mi `.htaccess` para obtener la URL amigable?

  ```
  RewriteRule ^noticias/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ all_sport.php?id=$1
  ```

Comment: Hola, para eso debes hacer varios cambios en el _.htaccess_, esta pregunta te puede ayudar [Eliminar extensiones php/html con .htaccess](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174146/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tu tabla debería tener un campo `id`, único, que sería la **primary key** de la tabla. Muchas veces este valor suele ser autoincremental para que no tengas que preocuparte de rellenarlo tú mismo.

Ese `id` será el que utilices en tu url. Lo que viene detrás realmente no es importante para hacer el redirect. Incluso aquí mismo en Stack Overflow. Prueba a modificar esta misma url cambiando el "título" del final. Verás que al recargar se carga la pregunta que toca y restaura el título. Esto es porque realmente lo que importa es el id. Utiliza ese id para recuperar la pregunta (y su título entre otras cosas) y luego utiliza el título para completarlo en la barra del navegador.

Únicamente, además del id, podrías necesitar la primera parte: 'noticia'. Si es que estás trabajando con diferentes tablas (una de noticia, otra de mundial...) porque entonces el id se refiere a la tabla anterior.

Así pues:

1. Modifica la/s tabla/s para que la clave primaria sea un id. Hazlo de tipo auto incremental
2. Utiliza la siguiente regla en el htaccess:

   Si lo tienes todo en una tabla:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^noticias/([^/]+)/?$ all_sport.php?id=$1
   ```

   Por contra, si hay diferentes tablas:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ all_sport.php?id=$2&cat=$1
   ```

   En ambos casos ignoramos lo que venga después del id porque podría ser que no esté o porque podría haber sido modificado por el usuario. Cuando recuperemos el título de base de datos lo pondremos en la url.
3. Dentro de tu php, basado en los datos que recibes, deberás hacer una consulta a base de datos y recuperar el registro. Recuperarás además un título.
4. Utilizarás el título recuperado para crearte un nuevo título amigable para url. Esto lo puedes hacer con [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) y una de las cosas que deberías hacer es cambiar los blancos por guiones.
5. Actualizarás la url con el título. Para ello deberás quitar el título anterior (si lo hubiera) y agregar el que acabas de recuperar y modificar. También deberás hacerlo con preg_replace.
6. Dependiendo de cómo lo hagas, podría pasar que al actualizar la url se vuelva a recargar (inútilmente) la página. Pero se puede evitar. En [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) de Stack Overflow se habla de cómo actualizar la url sin recargar la página.
7. Finalmente, cuando crees enlaces a otras páginas `<a href...` recuerda a poner el mismo formato (id + título modificado)

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar esto:

```
RewriteRule ^c/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$ url.php?dato1=$1&dato2=$2&dato2=$3
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

El objetivo es crear una url del estilo example.com/noticias/171210/mundial-rusia-2018/

Primero debes de generar los enlaces amigables, para ello debes de hacer lo siguiente:

```
//De la consulta a nuestra base de datos obtendremos el id y el titulo de la noticia.
$id = $resultadoConsulta['Id'];
$titulo =  $resultadoConsulta['Titulo'];
$tituloAmigable = strtolower($titulo);
$tituloAmigable = str_replace(' ', '-', $tituloAmigable);
$urlAmigable = "http://example.com/noticias/".$id."/".$tituloAmigable."/"
echo "<a href='".$urlAmigable."'>".$titulo."</a>"
```

De esa forma generaras tus url amigables, las cuales estarán en los enlaces de cada noticia.
Ahora tus preguntas:
- ¿Qué columna y de qué tipo debo agregar en mi tabla para los ID únicos de las noticias?
El ID puede ser el mismo que tu ya tienes (de tipo Int), solo tienes que hacerlo no nulo, y que tenga auto incremento

```
`Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `Id_UNIQUE` (`Id` ASC)
```

¿Cómo generar el ID único automáticamente por cada publicación de una noticia?
El ID ira auto incrementando a medida vayas creando noticias, al momento de hacer el insert en tu base de datos ira generando el ID nuevo para cada noticia.

¿Qué cambios debo emplear, en mi .htaccess para obtener la URL amigable?

```
RewriteRule ^noticias/(.+)/(.+)/?$ all_sport.php?id=$1&titulo=$2
```

De esa forma recibirás en all_sport.php el Id de la noticia y ya realizar tu consulta en la base de datos

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo dedicado +1