# ¿Cómo crear URL amigables, llamadas directamente desde una columna de datos sin tener que agregar las categorías en el .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Estoy desarrollando una plataforma de noticias deportivas, la cual consta con 7 tablas distintas de registro de noticias deportivas, debido al diseño de mi portal, de la página principal, de la cual existen distintos diseños en miniaturas, como otros diseños medianos y más grandes, les [enlazo mi plataforma de noticias deportivas](http://futbolworldcup.com) la cual se darán cuenta porque utilizo el fin de utilizar varias tablas de noticias deportivas.

Ahora las noticias de cada `id` o articulo nuevo registrado en la base de datos, se muestra la información sobre los datos obtenidos de la **URL,** mediante:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $urlOne = $_GET['id'];
}

$url = str_replace("/","",$urlOne);
```

Luego de ello, se le pasa una condición a la consulta `WHERE url=?`

Ahora mi problema está en el diseño de las **URLs** amigables, a pesar que funciona perfectamente, existe un pequeño problema que no es tan grave pero que sí quizás a un futuro, por ejemplo al agregar más categorías a la **URL**

> Nota: No consto con un sistema de categorías, pero por medio del `.htaccess` es fácil dar la imaginación de que sí exista, a pesar de que no.

Al agregar categorías a la url, la quiero realzar directamente desde la columna `url` de las tablas de las noticias deportivas, para no tener que modificar mi `.htaccess` cada vez que exista una categoría nueva y así evitar hacer lo siguiente:

```
RewriteRule ^mundial/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail?id=$1
RewriteRule ^noticias/deportivas/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail_one.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^deportes/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail_two.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^plus/noticias/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail_three.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^news/noticias/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail_four.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^futbol/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail_five.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail_six.php?id=$1
```

> Claro que las modificaciones no serían problema si las manejo yo solo, pero a este sistema voy a implementar un sistema de reportaje donde usuarios van agregar noticias, y van insertar en la columna `url` la url, que ellos vean que está al acorde a su reportaje, es decir que el sistema no va generar una URL automáticamente sino los usuarios.

Ahora tomando como referencia una de las [respuestas de una de mis preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179701/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-id-%C3%BAnico-de-un-post-similar-a-stackoverflow/184211#184211) y al realizar practicas con el código `.htaccess` de la respuesta:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ detail?id=$2&cat=$1
```

Me di cuenta que aquel código funciona con una url, de la siguiente manera `example.com/noticia/mi-url-del.post/` sin tener que agregar al mismo `.htaccess` esto: `noticia` muy distinto a lo que yo empleaba en mi `.htaccess`.

Entonces mi idea es la siguiente, registrar la url a mi idea, a mi gusto, en la columna `url` de la siguiente forma:

```
id_sports  title  detail  url ...
   1      ...... ....... deportes/liga/futbol/español/otros/mas/categorias/mi-url-de-la-noticia/
```

Y que al visitar la misma:

```
example.com/deportes/liga/futbol/español/otros/mas/categorias/mi-url-de-la-noticia/
```

Se muestre los datos de la noticia sin problema, ahora no siempre va hacer 7 categorías `deportes/liga/futbol/español/otros/mas/categorias/` puede ser una, dos, tres o varias.

Entonces lo que yo deseo es que el `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ detail?id=$2&cat=$1
```

Ejecute la URL amigable, sin importar el sin número de categoría que existan en la **URL**, porque este código `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ detail?id=$2&cat=$1` solo funciona con una: `example.com/noticia/mi-url-del.post/`

***Existe la posibilidad desde que una simple linea de código***

*.htaccess* `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ all_sport.php?id=$2&cat=$1` pueda ejecutar una o dos, o varias categorías sin problema, o cuantas de ellas debo agregar en mi `.htaccess` para que no vaya existir errores, al visitar a una noticia que hayan añadido más de una categoría.

Comment: Hola, para que te podamos ayudar con mas detalle creo que es hora de que conozcamos un poco el diseño que tiene la base de datos, y en general tu proyecto. ¿La tabla sports es la que guarda todo el contenido de las noticias? ¿Hay alguna otra tabla similar, o siempre todas las noticias se guardan en sports? Ese `id_sports` es la clave primaria de la tabla?

Comment: Hola @Julio mi proyecto es el siguiente [Fútbol World Cup](http://futbolworldcup.com) mi idea es crear un blog y noticias deportivas de todos los países, al final integrar un sistema de usuario tipo reportero, pero eso es otro asunto, tengo diferentes tablas, con diferentes noticias, debido al diseñó del portal de la página principal, muchos dieran que no debería hacer así, pero desde una sola tabla no voy a poder crear el mismo diseño del portal, si lo puedes ver quizás me des la razón... Entonces como lo habías dicho, en tu código para diferentes tablas así es...

Comment: @Julio Por lo tanto, no siempre va hacer la misma variable del ID de aquel producto, debido a las diferentes tablas noticias su ID no será igual, por ello solo quiero tomarle importancia a la columna URL donde sea desde ahí que se obtenga la URL amigable agregando ahí mismo las categorías tal como di el ejemplo en mi pregunta, si desea un poco más detalle coméntame creo que aclaro todo lo que me has preguntado.

Comment: @Luis He agregado algunos detalles en mi pregunta, espero no tener problemas amigo :)

Comment: Eduardo, no soy muy bueno en redirecciones. Pero se me ocurre que, desde PHP una buena ayuda puede ser trabajar con `QUERY_STRING` para construir tus rutas amigables. Se trata de uno de los valores de [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php)  que trae información sobre la ruta que ha sido escrita. Sea como sea, si lo vas a hacer *a mano*, sin ningún CMS tipo Wordpress, deberás implementar tu propio código de `categorías-subcategorias-subsubcategorias-subsubsubcategorias.......subsubsubsub` y establecer control sobre él.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si esperas que tu php (detail.php o cualquier otro) reciba **varios parámetros (cat1, cat2, cat3, ...)** (uno para cada categoría), no se puede hacer sin saber el número máximo de cateogrías. Implicaría tener "infinitas reglas" (para 1 categoría, para 2, para 3, ... etc)

Quizás lo podrías subsanar estableciendo un límite de categorías, así podrías escribir todas las redirecciones de antemano. Pero no es algo muy elegante.

Sin embargo hay otra alternativa. El php, en el parámetro de categoría, en lugar de recibir una, podría recibirlas todas (separadas por "/"). Y luego en el php separas por barra para obtener así un array con todas las categorías.

Por ejemplo, en el .htaccess tendrías algo así:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)/([^/]+/?)$ detail.php?url=$2&categorias=$1
```

Esto lo que hará es capturar en el primer grupo (`$1`) las categorías y en el segundo (`$2`) la url ([Ver demo](https://regex101.com/r/DdYT7r/2/))

Y en detail.php:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
$categorias_texto = $_GET['categorias'];
$categorias = explode('/', $categorias_texto); //Tu array con las categorías
```

**Ejemplo:**

Un usuario carga esta dirección: ejemplo.com/deportes/liga/futbol/español/otros/mas/categorias/mi-url-de-la-noticia/

Tu apache, mediante la configuración nueva del htacess examinará la url y la dividirá en dos partes:

```
(1) deportes/liga/futbol/español/otros/mas/categorias

(2) mi-url-de-la-noticia/
```

Después le pasará estos datos a detail.php (por ejeplo) y la primera parte se lo pasará al parámetro "categorias" y la segunda parte a "url"

Esto es lo que luego podrá recibir tu php mediante la variable `$_GET`.

Entonces en el php, con `$_GET['url']` ya no tienes que hacer nada adicional. Pero las categorías te vendrán "todas juntas" en `$_GET['categorias']`.

Si es así como lo necesitas, perfecto, no has de hacer nada más. Pero si por el contrario necesitases pasar esas categorías a un array, podrías hacerlo con la función `explode`, separando por `/`

Comment: Puedes explicarme mejor me perdí en el `.htaccess` y ese código PHP para que?

Comment: He agregado un ejemplo que espero que lo aclare un poco mejor.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, las categorías del `.htaccess` pero en mi antiguo `.htaccess` redireccionaba siempre al final de la URL la barra `/` ese detalle es fundamental para mi.

Comment: Ha actualizado la respuesta. Se puede lograr simplemente haciendo que el segundo grupo de captura capture también la barra. Al principio la había dejado fuera porque pensaba que era más limpio así. Pero se puede cambiar sin problemas.

Comment: Genial! Amigo gracias, me puedes explicar como puedes obtener esto que muestra en su respuesta `deportes/liga/futbol/español/otros/mas/categorias` a mi esto: `$categorias_texto = $_GET['categorias'];` me muestra toda la url, completa, dominio, más otras cosas...

Comment: He actualizado la expresión regular. Mira a ver si ahora evita que salga el dominio en `$_GET['categorias']`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80800/discussion-between-eduardo-and-julio).

Answer (score 0):

### Interpretando la URL desde apache con .htaccess

Tienes por un lado el fichero `.htaccess`, este fichero es la forma que tiene apache de permitir cambios de configuración a nivel de directorio (esto puede variar según la configuración del administrador si no eres tú mismo).

Desde este fichero, y gracias al módulo de apache **mod_rewrite**, puedes crear direcciones URL más amigables.

```
RewriteRule pattern target [Flag1,Flag2,Flag3]
```

**RewriteRule**

pattern > Expresión regular de búsqueda

target > Sustitución

flags > etiquetas (modifican el comportamiento)
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

#### Ejemplo práctico

Tomando tu expresión `([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?$` sobre `example.com/noticia/mi-url-del.post/` obtenemos el siguiente resultado:

```
noticia/mi-url-del.post/
noticia [1]
mi-url-del.post [2]
```

https://regex101.com/r/n7XyRc/1/

Puedes ver desde el enlace el resultado de la captura más detallado.

Estos dos grupos de captura se identifican en el target como $1 y $2. Siendo enviados a tu archivo php que procesa esta información.

```
all_sport.php?id=$2&cat=$1
all_sport.php?id='mi-url-del.post'&cat='noticia'
```