# ¿Error en explode separador de carpeta?

Tags: php

En el siguiente código

```
<?php
$urlproducto = $_GET['url'];
$carpetas = $_GET['cat'];
$categoria = explode('/', $carpetas);
echo $categoria;
?>
```

me muestra el error de: `notice: array to string conversion line 4`

Necesito unificar las carpetas o categorías con el valor del producto que está en la URL.

así `carpeta/1222/hola-mundo`

Comment: fijate si cat no viene como cat[]

Comment: @aloMalbarez Es dato es correcto amigo, porque si hago esto: `echo $carpetas;` me imprime la carpeta `carpeta1222`

Comment: @aloMalbarez El error lo produce esto `$categoria = explode('/', $carpetas);` no se porque.

Comment: Podría hacer un `var_dump($carpetas)`

Comment: @CesarRomero Perdon haciendo el `var_dump($carpetas)` me muestra esto datos `string(127) y la ruta completa de la url`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una vez haces `explode` se convierte en array, y el error que te da es por intentar mostrar un array con un `echo`, tienes que recorrerlo con un bucle:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($categoria); $i++) {
  echo $categoria[$i];
}
```

Si buscas un parámetro en concreto, por ejemplo 1222 en 'carpeta/1222/hola-mundo', haces el echo de esa posición.

```
echo $categoria[1];
```

Para mostrar los dos primeros elementos del ejemplo anterior:

```
$url = $categoria[0]."/".$categoria[1];
echo $url;
```

**Mostrar URL uniendo dos variables**, edición para mostrar comentarios.

Después del explode unes los elementos que necesites del array y el producto. Comprueba que las posiciones son las correctas, y ten en cuenta que si cambias a un entorno diferente al de pruebas pueden cambiar.

```
 <?php
    $urlproducto = $_GET['url'];
    $carpetas = $_GET['cat'];
    $categoria = explode('/', $carpetas);
    $url = $categoria[7]."/".$categoria[8]."/".$categoria[9]."/".$urlproducto;
    echo $url;
    ?>
```

Comment: Claro amiga cierto es :), pero como muestra en una sola variable, la categoría y el valor de la URL es decir de esta manera: `carpeta/1222/hola-mundo` llamar toda esa URL mediante una sola variable quizás por ejemplo denominada `echo $url;`

Comment: Exactamente que tiene echo $carpetas? Sólo necesitas unir los elementos del array que quieres obtener

Comment: el `echo $carpetas;` imprime toda las categorias de la URL, ejemplo `categoria/algo/id1223post/` y el `echo $urlproducto;` muestra por ejemplo lo siguiente: `holo-mundo` la cual se debe unificar en una sola variable para imprimirla así `categoria/algo/id1223post/holo-mundo`

Comment: $url = $categoria."/".$urlproducto; con esto te queda en una única variable

Comment: Ese código va dentro del `for` verdad? pero si la añado tal cual me has comentado me muestra errores de `Notice: Array to string conversion` y imprime lo siguiente: `Array/hola-mundo`, creo que sería mejor editar nuevamente la respuesta ;)

Comment: @Carmen Interesante respuesta +1, sobre el `for` en tomar cierto valor de una ***URL*** deberías agregar un apartado debajo [___________] con lo que indica el SO, en su pregunta y comentario, saludos.

Comment: @Carmen Amiga si necesito añadir el `explode` porque solo el `echo $carpetas;` me está tomando toda la ruta de esta manera: `http//localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/proyect/categoria/algo/hola-mundo/` el código que estoy usando lo tome de un [ejemplo que encontré aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/184359/c%C3%B3mo-crear-url-amigables-llamadas-directamente-desde-una-columna-de-datos-sin)

Comment: Ahora lo edito @Tania

Comment: @Carmen Excelente gracias :) tan pocas líneas de código me hizo sufrir, que dolor de cabeza, ahora si voy a dar un suspiro descanso gracias.