# Consulta SQL en MySQL entre 3 tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo en MySql 3 tablas, de las cuales 1 contiene el codigo de las otras dos tablas intento hacer un select que me muestre la primera tabla y en vez de el ID de las otras 2 tablas me muestre el nombre que corresponda

```
tabla_1
int id_tabla1
varchar nombre_tabla1
int id_tabla2
int id_tabla3

tabla_2
int id_tabla2
varchar nombre_tabla2

tabla_3
int id_tabla3
varchar nombre_tabla3
```

El select que he intentado es este

```
Select * from tabla_1,tabla_2,tabla_3 where tabla_1.id_tabla2 = tabla_2.id_tabla2 and tabla_1.id_tabla3 =  tabla3.id_tabla3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es más claro usar `JOIN` para unir las tablas, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    t2.nombre_tabla2,
    t3.nombre_tabla3
FROM tabla_1 t1
    INNER JOIN tabla_2 t2 ON t1.id_tabla2=t2.id_tabla2
    INNER JOIN tabla_3 t3 ON t1.id_tabla3=t3.id_tabla3
```

Aquí, `t1, t2, t3` son alias para simplificar luego los `JOIN` y las columnas del `SELECT`.

En el `SELECT` puedes agregar las columnas que desees de cada tabla. Conviene siempre usar el alias de cada tabla para cada columna, de ese modo se evitan confusiones, sobre todo cuando hay columnas que se llaman igual y están en tablas diferentes.

Comment: los id de las tablas 2 y 3 deben ser estrictamente foráneas con la tabla 1 para usar JOIN?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano puedes darme alguna pequeña ayudita en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/184359/cómo-crear-url-amigables-llamadas-directamente-desde-una-columna-de-datos-sin) estoy trabajando con la respuesta de *Julio*, pero existe un pequeño problema, ya que esto `$categorias_texto = $_GET['categorias'];` me esta tomando toda esta ruta `http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/futbol/mundial/serie-a-barcelona-comienza-firme-la-etapa-con-un-triunfo-sobre-el-nacional-3-1/` y solo debería tomarse las categorías de la url, espero tengas tiempo para mirarla saludos :)

Comment: @Hersenfels no necesariamente, aunque no fuesen foráneos te traería los datos. Por ejemplo en las bases de datos `MyISAM` no existe el concepto de llave foránea y puedes hacer consultas basadas en `JOIN` como si estuvieras en `INNODB`. La desventaja es que en el caso de `MyISAM` no puedes aplicar restricciones de integridad referencial... y no sé si afectará en la eficacia de la consulta, por ejemplo, indexación y mayor rapidez de la consulta... sería tema para una interesante pregunta.

Comment: amigo, que pasa si  a la consulta sql que me mencionas, le tuviese que anidar un WHERE por ID de la tabla_1, como seria?

Comment: @Hersenfels se lo pones al final  por ejemplo ... `WHERE t1.id_tabla1 = 5` te traerá solamente los datos cuando el valor de `id_tabla1` sea igual a `5` en la `tabla1`.

Comment: eres un crack men